# Why is my NSPrintOperation print image truncating my Text() view but my screen image is displaying the same exact Text views just fine

Tags: swift, printing, view, truncation

First, I apologize for the lack of images. Apparently I'm still too new here to do that. I will attempt to describe the problem verbally, and provide the two key pieces of code.

I'm printing a tv schedule, with rows of time slots. When I display the view to my macos screen, it looks something like this:

```
40.    8:00 AM                    8:30 AM
CNN.   Bla Bla Bla Talk Show 1.   Whatever Talk Show 1, with
       Guests to discuss price    Great Host 
       of bla bla bla.            Host will talk about
                                  Whatever
```

But when I print it, it truncates some, but not necessarily all of the two-line text items, like so:

```
40.    8:00 AM                    8:30 AM
CNN.   Bla Bla Bla Talk Sh ...    Whatever Talk Show 1, w...
       Guests to discuss pr...    Host will talk about 
                                  Whatever
```

If you notice the inconsistency, that's because it isn't entirely consistent. Sometimes I do get the two-line output, but more often I get the truncation with the ellipsis. I haven't figured out the underlying pattern why. But only in the print frame is this a problem. The screen is displaying exactly what I want.

So I have hunted around for solutions, and have tried many variations of the Text() modifiers fixedSize() and lineLimit(). fixedSize sort of works, in that the two-line items don't truncate, but again, in the print view, the row with the tall cell clips the rows above and below it. It's really acting like the NSRect framing the print image just isn't big enough, but it's huge, and this shouldn't be happening.

The project is too big to provide all the code, but hopefully it will be enough to provide the view in question, plus the printer logic.

The View (this displays correctly - no truncation):

```
struct ScheduleDisplayView: View {
    
    var schedule: [SchedSlot]
    
    let chanmax: CGFloat = 28.0
    let fontsize: CGFloat = 7.0
    let cellmax: CGFloat = 120
    
    var sortedData : [DayBlock] {
        let schedTree: ScheduleTree = ScheduleTree.init()
        for ss in schedule {
            schedTree.add(schedSlot: ss)
        }
        return schedTree.dayList
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(sortedData, id: \.dateStamp) { day in
                Text("\(day.dateStamp)")
                    .bold()
                ForEach(day.qList, id: \.QTag) { qblock in
                    ForEach(qblock.chanList.sorted(by: <), id: \.chanTag) { channel in
                        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                Text(String(channel.chanTag))
                                Text(channel.callSign.prefix(4))
                            }
                            .border(Color.yellow)
                            .frame(maxWidth: chanmax, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .padding(0)
                            ForEach(channel.timeList, id: \.timeTag) { timecell in
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    Text("\(timecell.timeTag)")
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                                    ForEach(timecell.cellList, id: \.id) { cell in
                                        if cell.startTime != timecell.timeTag {
                                            Text("\(cell.title) (\(cell.startTime))")
                                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                                                .lineLimit(2)
                                        } else {
                                            Text(cell.title)
                                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                                                .lineLimit(2)
                                        }
                                        Text(cell.subtitle)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                                            .lineLimit(2)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .border(Color.green)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        .font(.system(size: fontsize))
                        .border(Color.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the printing function. It is still lacking pagination functionality, but it's what I've got so far:

```
func printScheduleView(schedule: [SchedSlot] ) {
    
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared
    printInfo.topMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.leftMargin = 0.0
    
    printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fit
    printInfo.verticalPagination = .automatic
    printInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = false
    printInfo.isVerticallyCentered = false

    let view = ScheduleDisplayView(schedule: schedule)
    let contentRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 900, height: 2800)

    let viewToPrint = NSHostingView(rootView: view)
    viewToPrint.frame = contentRect

    let bitMap = viewToPrint.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: contentRect)!
    viewToPrint.cacheDisplay(in: contentRect, to: bitMap)

    let image = NSImage(size: bitMap.size)
    image.addRepresentation(bitMap)

    let imageView = NSImageView(frame: contentRect)
    imageView.image = image

    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: imageView, printInfo: printInfo)
    printOperation.showsPrintPanel = true
    printOperation.showsProgressPanel = true
    printOperation.run()
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to my use of the List view. It appears the limitations of the vertical scroll window somehow get imported into the printer function and compress the print image's vertical space. So that's why there was such a difference between the screen vs the printer version of the same exact view. I 'fixed' it by replacing the List with a VStack. No more truncation is happening.